# How to check from cloud trail deleted policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

We have one role which has 8 policies attached to it. One policy has been removed by someone, now how to identify when it was removed. How to check from cloud trail?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible event types, depending on if a managed policy or an inline policy has been removed from the role:

- [DetachRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DetachRolePolicy.html) for managed policies
- [DeleteRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteRolePolicy.html) for inline policies

You can [filter the CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html) event history by either of these to find and analyze the respective events.

Please note that if you haven’t explicitly [created a trail in AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html), the events are only retained for 90 days.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer, I can find it in cloudtrail event history.
[image]